# Add User to Exchange In-placeHold/eDiscovery (In-Situ) with powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, exchange-server

I'm currently encountering some problems with powershell, while creating scripts.
I want to add a User to our In-place-Hold / eDiscovery. I more or less found a workaround to adding a single User to the list, but I'm not sure if it works without losing data of the already existing In-Place-Hold users.

The goal is to add newly created users to an existing In-Place-Hold.

However, maybe its easier to understand with my code:

```
#All users that are already in the in-situ
$check = Get-MailboxSearch “In situ autotest"

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
       $Username    = $User.username
       $Firstname   = $User.firstname
       $Lastname    = $User.lastname

      if (Get-Mailbox -Identity $Username)
      {
           #If user does exist, output a warning message
           Write-Warning "Benutzername $Username already existing on the Exchange Server."
      }
      else
      {
           Enable-Mailbox -Identity "$Username" -DomainController 'DC.domain.com'
      }

      #search for the user
      $Add = Get-Mailbox -Identity "$Username"
      $check.sources.add("$Add")
}

#write all users back into insitu mailbox
Set-Mailboxsearch -Name "In situ autotest" -Identity "In situ autotest" -SourceMailboxes $check.sources
```

Does someone know if there is an easier way to add a single user to the sourcemailboxes of Set-Mailboxsearch, without having to aplly everyone again?

Thank you guys very much in advance!